# In an IOS app using Swift, How do I bundle a binary file with the app? and how do I read it into a byte array?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle, binaryfiles, randomaccessfile

I have a binary file. How do I bundle it into my IOS app and then read it into byte array with random access?

I have searched solutions with "IOS Swift read bundled binary file with random access" and couldn't find a complete example.

Comment: In iOS these are called "assets." See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/asset-management for an explanation of how to use them. A "byte array" is called Data. (It's not clear what you mean by "with random access," though. Data always has random access.)

Comment: I am new to Swift and IOS, by saying random access; I mean seeking to a specific file location and reading xxx bytes into a byte array, and then re-seek to another position and read some other bytes without closing the file.

Comment: Swift has a [FileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) which is very similar to C/C++ random access file handling. 
So you add your file as [asset](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingDataSets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH72-SW1) in project, use [Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) to locate it and `FileHandle` to read it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.